# Replace value of line in yml with Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have yml file in below format.

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "testuser/backend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "testuser/frontend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```

How to replace 'Image', 'ImageTag' for Backendapp through Bash?

Edit: say file name is test.yml with above contents. Then, I would like to replace 'Image' and 'ImageTag' with some another value(say 'teststring','latest2' resp.) for 'Backendapp' part.

Modified file should look like below.

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "teststring"
  ImageTag: "latest2"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "testuser/frontend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```

Comment: are there any sections besides `Backendapp` and `Frontendapp`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes.. other sections might get added with different names but with same keys such as 'Image', 'ImageTag'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '
/:$/{
  flag=""
}
/Backendapp/||/Frontendapp/{
  flag=1
}
flag && NF && (/Image:/||/ImageTag:/){
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  $NF="teststring";
  print val $0;
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest
  Image: teststring
  ImageTag: teststring
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: teststring
  ImageTag: teststring
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```

***Solution 2nd:*** As per OP, OP needs to have shell variable into `awk` variable too then following may help on same:

```
awk -v val_shell="$shell_variable" '
/:$/{
  flag=""
}
/Backendapp/||/Frontendapp/{
  flag=1
}
flag && NF && (/Image:/||/ImageTag:/){
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  $NF=val_shell;
  print val $0;
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Comment: @AVJ, so above code looks for either `Backendapp` or `Frontendapp` so in case you only want to look for 1 string then you could remove it from code then.

Comment: Thanks. It's replacing 'Image' and 'ImageTag' names, But I want it to replace values for those keys.
ex: 'Image: latest' should become 'Image: teststring'

Comment: @RaviderSingh13 .. yes it works.. But 'Image' or 'ImageTag' words looses 2 space characters before them

Comment: Please check updates in question. you're solution is working.. But indention is getting lost for lines whose values got replaced. i.e, 'Image' and 'ImageTag' are coming in line with 'Backendapp', loosing 2 space character before it.
How to maintain indention?

Comment: @AVJ, please check my code now, it should take care of indentation let me know if any queries on same.

Comment: can you please update awk command with double quotes.. Because 'teststring' is going to be a variable value and that variable should be substitued in awk command

Comment: @AVJ, try my solution 2nd and let me know if that helps, I am considering that you want a shell variable's value into `awk`.

Comment: how to replace the Backendapp with a shell variable , can't get this working

Comment: @FreshMike, please open a thread for it or search forum for answers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770547/use-bash-variable-in-awk-search

Answer (score 2):

Here's your solution. It basically uses SED to do the replacement. Just copy and paste the bits between "START OF SCRIPT" and "END OF SCRIPT" into any bash script then run (simple instructions below):

### START OF SCRIPT ...

```
#!/bin/bash

# SED script will be stored here ...

sedscript=/tmp/sedscript.sed

# first argument to script is the parent name ...

parent="${1}"

# second argument to the script is child name...

child="${2}"

# third argument is the value to replace the CHILD value with ...

value="$3"

cat << EOF > "${sedscript}"

# find parent ...
/^${parent}:.*$/{

    p

    # load next line into input ...
    n

    # another parent found to print it ...
    /^[a-z|A-Z|0-9]\{1\}:.*$/{

        # we have found another parent
        # so stop processing ...

        b print_default_text
    }

    :search_for_child

    /^[ |   ]*$child[ | ]*:.*$/{

        s/^\([^:]*:[ |\"|   ]*\)[^\"]*\(.*\)$/\1$value\2/p

        b dont_print_default_text
    }

    p
    n
    b search_for_child
}


:print_default_text
p

:dont_print_default_text
```

EOF

```
sed -n -f "${sedscript}" "input.yml"
```

## ... END OF SCRIPT

Now we save the script as alter.sh (for example) then run it like this (changing the Frontendapp/Image to "another-image-name"):

./alter.sh Frontendapp Image "another-image-name"

#### INPUT FILE ....

Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "teststring"
  ImageTag: "latest2"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "testuser/frontend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2

## Output file ....

Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "teststring"
  ImageTag: "latest2"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "another-image-name"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2

Note: the script takes care of quotes too, i.e. if the original value has quotes then the new value will be surrounded in quotes also.

Hope this helps ....

Comment: Thanks Mohammad - I'm new to this ;)

Comment: it gives me error "sed: file /tmp/sedscript.sed line 10: Invalid range end"

Comment: I've edited it - school boy error. The expression was 'a-z|A-z|..' when it should have been 'a-z|A-Z' i.e. upppercase 'Z' for 'A-Z' range. Please try again. Make sure the input file has linefeeds too, as per original text of this ticket.

Comment: works like a charm.. But already using awk solution suggested above.

Comment: AWK or SED ... no matter ... any of these utilities are boss ;)

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NF==1 && /^[^[:space:]]+:/{ f=(/^(Back|Front)endapp:/) }
     f && $1 ~ /^Image(Tag)?:/{ $1="  teststring" }1' test.yml
```

The output:

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest
  teststring: "testuser/backend"
  teststring: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  teststring: "testuser/frontend"
  teststring: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```