# Use bash variable in awk search

Tags: bash, awk, sed

HI My trying to replace this code with another bash variable

```
   awk -v val_shell="$shell_variable" -v name="$shell_variable2" '
/:$/{
  flag=""
}
/Backendapp/{
  flag=1
}
flag && NF && (/ImageTag:/){
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  $NF=val_shell;
  print val $0;
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

How do I add another variable from bash to replace the 'Backendapp'?
I tried $0 ~ name instead of /Backendapp/ but still no luck.

Input:

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "testuser/backend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "testuser/frontend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```

Desired output:

```
Backendapp:
  Name: spring-rest 
  Image: "testuser/backend"
  ImageTag: "0.2.3"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Port: 8080
  replicaCount: 2

Frontendapp:
  Name: spring-js
  Image: "testuser/frontend"
  ImageTag: "latest"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicaCount: 2
```

BASH variables:

```
shell_variable=0.2.3
shell_variable2=Backendapp
```

Trying to the ~ option here:

```
  awk -v val_shell="$shell_variable" -v name="$shell_variable2" '
/:$/{
  flag=""
}
$0 ~ name {
  flag=1
}
flag && NF && (/ImageTag:/){
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  $NF=val_shell;
  print val $0;
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Thanks for any advise

Comment: could you add what value you saved in `name`? was it `Backendapp` or `/Backendapp/` or something else?

Comment: Kindly add sample input and sample output in you code to make your request more clear.

Comment: Added more explanation @Sundeep it's: Backendapp

Comment: Can you show `$0 ~ name` not working (and thus, exactly how you defined and used it)? It **absolutely should** work, if it were implemented correctly. A good [mcve] here would focus in on the specific problem, showing only the shortest code that lets someone else reproduce it (and removing everything unnecessary or irrelevant).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added example code

Comment: See https://ideone.com/icLNnN -- your example code works fine; the output has `ImageTag: NewTag`, as it should. BTW, a good MCVE can just be copied-and-pasted to see the problem, without needing to set variables or create files beforehand. (I'm assuming it's actually in the variables' values that our problem lives, so the very act of trying to create a MCVE probably would have revealed the issue).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy hmmm you are right ..

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to work. Maybe you are including too much regex info?

```
(pi4 525) $ match="l"
(pi4 526) $ (echo alpha;echo beta;echo gamma;echo delta) | awk -v var="$match" '$0 ~ var'
alpha
delta
```